# I can't reset an expired password because it is expired. What's next?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, active-directory

The password of my corporate (Active Directory based) account expired this morning. When logging in, I see an error similar to:

> Your password has expired and must be changed.

I'm then invited to enter a new password. Once my new, never used before password is  submitted, I see a different error:

> The password of the account has expired.

Searching for this error in Google, I only see people encountering this error in SQL Server or when authenticating programmatically.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Update your question with that information.  The solution to this problem can only be solved by having AD Administrator level access.

Comment: Sounds like an odd glitch. You should be able to reset your password after it's expired. Have someone with admin privileges manually reset your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you yourself are the domain administrator, follow this articles suggestion.

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1328-unlock-domain-users-or-reset-passwords-from-command-line

```
net user loginname newpassword /DOMAIN /Active:Yes
```

or there is a powershell version

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/17/how-to-change-a-user-s-active-directory-password-with-powershell.aspx

Set-AdUserPwd.ps1

```
Function Set-AdUserPwd
{
Param(
[string]$user,
[string]$pwd
) #end param
$oUser = [adsi]"LDAP://$user"
$ouser.psbase.invoke("SetPassword",$pwd)
$ouser.psbase.CommitChanges()
} # end function Set-AdUserPwd
Set-AdUserPwd -user "cn=bob,ou=HSG_TestOU,dc=nwtraders,dc=com" -pwd P@ssword1
```

Comment: Does resetting the password fix this permanently? I have the same issue and resetting fixes but the same issue occurs when the password next expires.